# SDA has to wait around one second to go high when reading hex is 0xF8

Tags: i2c

When I was trying to read 0xF8 from slave, the SDA is still low.

```
b"0111_0000", -- 38 slave address (write)
b"0000_0000", -- 00 register address
b"1000_1111", -- 8F data
b"0111_0000", -- 38 slave address (write)
b"1010_0100", -- A4 register address
b"0000_0000", -- 00 data (enable interrupt to host)
b"0111_0000", -- 38 slave address (write)
b"1000_0000", -- 80 register address (describe valid touching detect threshold) 
b"0000_1111", -- 0F data   
b"0111_0000", -- 38 slave address (write)
b"1000_1000", -- 88 register address (describe valid touching detect threshold) 
b"0000_1100", -- 0C data       
b"0111_0000", -- 38 slave address (write)
b"1010_0001", -- A1 register address
b"0111_0001", -- 38 slave address (read)
b"0111_0000", -- 38 slave address (write)
b"1010_0010", -- A2 register address        
b"0111_0001", -- 38 slave address (read)
```

Whole code initialization used by the master is above.

Datasheet of the slave chip is here (https://threefivedisplays.com/wp-content/uploads/datasheets/touch_driver_datasheets/FT5206_REV_0_4_%20APP.pdf)

As you can see from the datasheet, this IC is used by touch screen to read touch value.

You can see that from the first picture that the SDA is low even though SCL is high for quite a while. The message I am trying to send is a stop according to IIC protocol.

[image: it's not going high]

You can see from 2nd picture when I was trying to read 0x30 from slave, the slave is high.

[image]

The 3rd picture shows that SDA goes high anyway after one second (very long time) when read value is 0xF8.
[image]

Scope diagram of the IIC is here.

[image]

Second oscilloscope diagram is here.

[image]
Can anyone explain what happened here?

Comment: It would help if you edit your question to give a little more context about what devices these are, and what you're doing with them. It's possible someone who knows I2C better than me can answer from just what you've provided, but often it will depend on the behavior of the specific device.

Comment: Likely a bug in your master source code. But without knowing which MCU this is, what code it runs, and what the slave chip is, it's impossble to answer.

Comment: @GlennWillen I have just uploaded the link for the datasheet of the slave.

Comment: @Justme I have just uploader link for the datasheet of the slave.

Comment: @kile Sorry but alone that is useless. This is unlikely to be the fault of the slave chip alone, as it depends how this chip is connected to your MCU in hardware, and what code your MCU runs to initialize the IO pins and handle the I2C bus.

Comment: @Justme please have a look at the initialization code.

Comment: @kile Ah I remember this FPGA stuff now. Well, scope waveforms would help. They showed where the previous problems were. Although, my next question is, does the FPGA send a NAK or ACK when it has transferred the last byte out it wants to read? Are you sure there is no bug in the FPGA that keeps SDA low or what would be the reason why FPGA would not let SCL high?

Comment: @Justme I used FPGA to set SCL is in Z (high impedance). FPGA send ACK when it has sent last byte. Scope waveform is uploaded now.

Comment: Ah, so there's the problem then.

Comment: @Justme Can you pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Your rising edges are all suspiciously sharp for I2C, unless your clock speed is very slow and/or your pullups are very strong. Are you sure you have your I2C master's pins correctly configured in open-drain mode?

Comment: @brhans The clock speed is around 24kHz. Is it slow enough to cause this problem?

Comment: @brhans This was extensively handled in previous related questions. It was a problem that pins were push-pull. Notice that there is no overshoot spike on rising edges (like there are on falling edges) so I presume the pins are not push-pull any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have transferred the last byte you want to read, you ACK the byte.

That is incorrect, you must NAK the last byte.

If you ACK the byte, the slave IC thinks you want to receive a next byte too and starts transmitting it out. So that is why SDA is low and you can't send out a stop, because you can't release the SDA after setting SCL high if the slave is keeping the SDA low.

If you NAK the byte, the slave will no longer drive any data out after the NAK, leaves the SDA floating high, and the FPGA is free to pull SDA down, release SCL high, and release SDA.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! this problem bothers me for a week. But why does it work if the read data is other than 0xF8 even when master send ack?

Comment: @kile That's because after ACK there is already first bit of next byte on the bus, and when reading register index 0xA1 it returns data bytes 0x30 and something with MSB high next; while reading register index 0xA2 it returns data bytes 0xF8 and something with MSB low. If the registers are as usual and register index is auto-incrementing, you could assume reading two bytes starting from index 0xA1 will return data from 0xA1 and 0xA2 so in fact after 0x30, there could be 0xF8, and there could be something with MSB 0 on 0xA3.

Comment: How can I see the MSB bit of next byte? Is it possible to see the MSB bit?

Comment: @kile You are already seeing it if you send ACK bit, as after ACK bit the slave is already transmitting out the MSB of the next byte you did not want.